# Move Magento to new domain & server results in default homepage

Tags: magento

I have just moved a Magento install from one server to another, and this is a change of domain too. I have moved all files from one /httpdocs directory to another /httpdocs directory.

I have uploaded the new database and imported the data as well as updated the local.xml file to point to the new database.

But when the site loads I get a default looking Magento page, rather than the correctly skinned Magento store.

Is there some config I have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make changes in your DB :

In core_config_data table, the values you need to change are in the path column. Change the `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` to match the new domain name by altering the value column for both records.

After that clear all catch, may you forget to do this step.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here, look at **step 4**. http://www.atwix.com/magento/moving-magento-to-another-server/

Answer (score 0):

Log in to admin panel and go to System->Configuration->GENERAL/Design

Open package and themes, then set your custom package & themes name here. After that clear all cache from System->Manage Cache.

Hope it will work!